# Determine the coordinate to achieve desired distance from a given coordinate

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm working on a software project where I need to determine the $(x_2,y_2)$ coordinate on a $2D$ plane where I already know the $(x_1,y_1)$ and distance line segment should have.

Is there any way that I can achieve this ?

Comment: Isn't that the circle of points $(x_2,y_2)$ around $(x_1,y_1)$ as the midpoint with the distance as the radius? If so, then there is no unique solution $(x_2,y_2)$ anyway.

Comment: Yes, it is. But, set an angle(say 60 degrees) do we have any solution ?

Comment: You need to more clearly specify the problem.  What is the input, and what is the desired output?  Your comment adds a needed piece of data, but gives the impression that we will always have the angle as well as the original data.  Is that true?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the magnitude $r$ *and the polar angle* $\theta$ of the vector from $(x_1,y_1)$ to $(x_2,y_2)$, then you can find 
$$x_2=x_1+r\cos \theta,\quad y_2=y_1+r\sin \theta$$
For more, see [polar coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system).